# Show only years in UIDatePicker in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I would like to show only year in UIDatePicker from Calender, right now I have day, month & year but I want only month and year.
If anyone could help me will be appreciate & I know about libraries but I don't want to use it.

Regards,
[image]